# How to fix W3WP error happening in IIS while generating Crystal report and downloading in binary format

Tags: c#, wcf, crystal-reports, report

I'm trying to generate crystal report in server using WCF and downloading in binary format to client machine. Service is calling from wpf application in loop.It will generate report for some records and then it will throw the w3wp. exe error. I monitored the error using Debug Diag tool and got a following summary in log

```
|---------------------------------------------------------|
| Count | Exception                                       |
|---------------------------------------------------------|
| 1926  | System.String                                   |
| 41    | 0XE06D7363                                      |
| 2     | System.AppDomain                                |
| 2     | System.InvalidOperationException                |
| 2     | System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback      |
| 1     | 0XE0434F4E                                      |
| 1     | CrystalDecisions.Shared.CrystalReportsException |
|---------------------------------------------------------|
```

I'm not able track the correct cause of error?

Comment: Its failing in Crystal at this call `CrystalDecisions.Shared.CrystalReportsException`, suggest you look through the Crystal log files and turn up the verbosity of logging. Also check the Event Logs for clues.

Comment: Check if IIS process which is w3wp.exe is still alive in task manager after the crash.

Comment: try to grant the WCF the highest executable privilege(the application pool->application identity)

Comment: Thanks every one for the reply.